# Accessing a model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, model, helper

After `Post.all`, I'm trying to return a JSON array of post objects with a custom attribute. Here is what I have:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:profil).page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
render json: @posts.to_json(:include => :profil,
                            :methods => [:image_url, :vote_modificator])
```

This method correctly returns a list of posts, including `Profil` and a custom attribute `image_url`. I have a model `Vote`, which belongs to `Profil` and `Post`:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value
  belongs_to :profil
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I want to insert in each post the `Vote` value corresponding to itself and the `current_user` defined like that in `application_controller.rb`:

```
  def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token] 
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

I tried to add a method in `to_json`, but the method defined in model can't access this helper. Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Since nobody has replied yet: search Google for "rails access current user from model". You will find a lot of discussion on this issue and a lot of different solutions and suggestions. It's not such an easy problem to solve elegantly, which is probably the reason you didn't get a reply yet.